# How to use the jQuery DataTables order listener

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I am using the DataTable jQuery plugin (http://datatables.net/) and I would like to disable the default ordering of each column when you click on the TH element and instead specify another element for ordering (which will be a child of each TH).

I have this in JS

```
var table = $('.table-striped').DataTable({
    "ordering": false
    });
table.order.listener( $('#sort'), 1);
```

And this in HTML

```
<table class="table table-striped" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><span id="sort">Col 1</span></th>
            <th>Col 2</th>
            <th>Col 3</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><span>2</span></td>
            <td><span>CHARLIE</span></td>
            <td><span>DELTA</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><span>1</span></td>
            <td><span>ALPHA</span></td>
            <td><span>BETA</span></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/d20djg91/)

So I believe that when clicking on the SPAN with ID of 'sort', the table should be sorted by column 1- however it does not :( Any ideas??

BTW, jQuery & DataTables are all initalised correctly and I can get other DataTable functionality like pagination working :)

Comment: That's a tough one. It should be working. I'd post in the DataTables forum. Allan has been very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, my solution was to enable the default order on DataTables, and then to prevent the ordering event having an affect on elements [that I didnt want the sort event to work on] in the TH with a return false:

```
var table = $('.table-striped').DataTable({
"ordering": true
});

$('.table-striped th div').click(function() {
return false;
})

<table class="table table-striped" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th><span id="sort">Sort me</span><div>No sort</div></th>
        <th>Col 2</th>
        <th>Col 3</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><span>2</span></td>
        <td><span>CHARLIE</span></td>
        <td><span>DELTA</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><span>1</span></td>
        <td><span>ALPHA</span></td>
        <td><span>BETA</span></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
```

Hope that helps!